# TSP solver without triangle inequality

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, grid, traveling-salesman

I am interested in solving the TSP for (small) grid graphs. Any sort of library will do for me, but this seems to be harder than expected. I tried a couple of solvers I found out there (including concorde), but they all seem to have problems when the triangle inequality does not hold.

For instance, I would like the solver to output the tour (0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3) for the graph (with unit edge weights) below:

```
0-1-2
| |
3-4
```

In this particular case, I told concorde that the edge (2, 4) had weight 1000 and concorde promptly produced the tour (0, 1, 2, 4, 3) of cost 1004. This is clearly not what I am looking for.

Ideally, there would be some simple (possibly brute force) implementation in Java, but anything which works will actually do. Can anyone point me to some code or do I really have to go an implement this myself?

Edit: also, it is important that I get an exact solution, not some approximation.

Edit2: indeed, this does not seem to be TSP. What I am trying to find is a shortest closed walk which visits all vertices.

Comment: Are you sure you are applying Concorde correctly? It's supposed to be an *exact* solver for the symmetric TSP problem...

Comment: @Li-aungYip: Concorde is actually giving the optimal TSP solution. The problem is that OP is expecting a solution that isn't a valid TSP tour. See my answer for details.

Comment: I see. In fact, given that graph, I don't think there is *any* other closed cycle that visits all nodes. (key word: closed. 2-1-0-3-4 has weight 4 and visits all nodes, but it's not closed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your difficulty is not the triangle inequality. The difficulty has to do with the fact that the solution you're expecting is not a valid [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) tour.

The TSP seeks a [Hamiltonian cycle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html); that is, a cycle that visits each vertex exactly once. Your solution, `(0, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3)`, visits vertex 1 twice.

If that's the solution you're seeking, then the the problem you're trying to solve is not the Travelling Salesman Problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! So I guess I should first compute the distance matrix between all vertices in my graph and then solve TSP. That should give me the length of an optimal tour in my grid. Correct?

Comment: @Duh: Frankly, I don't see how that would help transform your problem into the TSP. In any case, I think a useful first step is to figure out what it is exactly that you're seeking (the shortest cycle that visits each vertex *at least* once?)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am looking for. And in this case, moving the problem to the complete graph with accurate distances solved the problem:
- It is easy to show that the lengths of the optimal solutions are equal
- Is is easy to build a tour in my sense from the optimal TSP tour in the complete graph

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to forbid the edge `(2, 4)`. If you take then the typical TSP algorithms, when they end up in node `2` (the only way they could come from was `1`), then there is no way to another node that they haven't visited so far.

What you can do is define the distances between each node as the distance of the shortest paths between them, thus for example the distance edge `(2, 4)` = distance path `(2, 1, 4)`. Finally you take the solution from the solver `(0, 1, 2, 4, 3)` and replace every non-existent edge like `(2, 4)` with its shortest path `(2, 1, 4)` and you'll end up with your desired solution.